# How to upload a image file to a oracle database using Python Flask

Tags: python, oracle, flask

I am trying to update a row in my oracle database with a image file (into a blob column) and the file name (varchar2 column).

Below is my code, if I put `f.filename` in the parenthesis of `f.read()`, then I get error "**expecting a integer as parameter**" and if I put nothing there then I get "**cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number**" on `cur.execute` line.

How do I modify the below code update the row with my image file? Thanks. I am new to python and trying to learn on my own.

```
    v_sql = "update login_table set image_file= %s and binary_file = %s where email_address= %s"            
    v_binary_file = f.read() 
    v_current_user = 'abcd@abcd.com'
    v_args = (f.filename, v_binary_file, v_current_user)
    cur.execute(v_sql, v_args)
    cur.commit
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's bind variable syntax uses a colon (':') not a percent ('%') prefix for statement placeholders.

The [cx_Oracle manual LOB documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html) has clear LOB examples:

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    textdata = f.read()

with open('image.png', 'rb') as f:
    imgdata = f.read()

cursor.execute("""
        insert into lob_tbl (id, c, b)
        values (:lobid, :clobdata, :blobdata)""",
        lobid=10, clobdata=textdata, blobdata=imgdata)
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I could get it to work the way you explained, but I had to use hardcoded file name as I could not tell the code the path of the file. How do I tell "with open(f.filename, 'rb')" the path of my file? I get "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20190828_170339.jpg' when I don't hardcode it. File is being uploaded by a html form and gets stored in "/static/images" folder on my dev box

Comment: Okay, I got it after keeping on trying, I am new to stackoverflow and below pasted code is not showing up with indents and other formating.
`code 
v_filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(f.filename))
v_filename = f.filename
v_useridentifier =  current_user.email_address
with open(v_filepath, 'rb') as f: 
       photo = f.read()  code`